# add leave or stay on the page alert in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, popup, ionic3

I'm trying to add a popup that will be shown on a page when the user starts to populate data in the form and then he decided to go somewhere else in the app.

This popup will show this message: 'Do you want to leave this page and save your changes?' 
three buttons are available: Stay, Leave and Save before leaving.
I'm new to ionic logic and I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I started by adding a button in the page that shows the popup (Still don't know how to trigger the event when the user clicks on any link of the sidebar for example). when the user clicks on that button the popup is shown with the three buttons.

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the handlers of these buttons.

This is what I have in the `ts` file :

```ts
leaveOrStayModal() {
   let e = event || window.event;
   e.stopPropagation();
   this.alertMixin.presentAlert(
  'Do you want to leave this site?\n',
  "You haven't saved your changes!",
  'Stay',
  'Leave',
  'Save',
  null,
  () => {
    console.log('leave handler')
    // this.navCtrl.push()  Here I don't know how to get the exact link clicked from the sidebar ? to go to 
  },
  () => {
    console.log('Save handler') 
 //here I want to save the form ?
  }
 )
 }
```

the popup code:

```
presentAlert(title: string, message: string, btnOneText: string, btnTowText: string, btnThreeText: string,
                      btnOneHandler?: () => void, btnTowHandler?: () => void, btnThreeHandler?: () => void,
                      present: boolean = true) {
     let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
     title: title,
     message: message,
     buttons: [
      {
      text: btnOneText,
      handler: () => {
        if (btnOneHandler) {
          btnOneHandler();
        }
      }
     },
    {
      text: btnTowText,
      handler: () => {
        if (btnTowHandler) {
          btnTowHandler();
        }
      }
     },
     {
      text: btnThreeText,
      handler: () => {
        if (btnThreeHandler) {
          btnThreeHandler();
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
 if (present) {
   confirm.present().then();
 }
 return confirm;
```

}

And this is the button that shows the popup (to be removed )

```html
<button ion-button icon-left item-right type="button" (click)="leaveOrStayModal()"> Click to show modal </button>
```

Comment: Can you add the modal page code?

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Still not clear... what do you mean by links in sidebar ? also this is an alert without any form. Not a popup/modal

Comment: This is the scenario: in the main page there's a form , the user starts to fill in the input texts, then he decided ( for some reason ) to go to the sidebar and navigate to another page (without finishing what he has just doing ).. this  popup should appear to ask him if he is sure to leave he page or to save what he has typed before leaving. I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: I have added the button in the main page containing the form for test reasons ..

Answer (score 2):

You should leverage life cycle hook ionViewCanLeave for that. Some basic documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

For your context I just drafted the way I would do it (its a bit dirty):

```
userCanLeave = false;
ionViewCanLeave() {
// here you can use other vars to see if there are reasons we want to keep user in this page:
  if (!this.userCanLeave) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Are you sure?',
          message: 'The form data may be lost',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Stay',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('User stayed');
                this.userCanLeave = false;
                reject();
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Leave',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('User leaves');
                this.userCanLeave = true;
                resolve();
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Save',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('User saved data');
                // do saving logic
                this.userCanLeave = true;
                resolve();
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    } else { return true }
  }
```

userCanLeave - here is just example of a var that defines if the page has the state where we would not want a user to leave "freely".

then we use promise to ensure that user can not leave without answering dialogue options, we wait for their answers to define whether life cycle hook gets true/false flag to proceed.

Please note also that this life cycle hook only "kicks in" when a view (page) gets off the stack (pops) if you would push in a new view - it won't guard that. But in this case new pushed in page won't destroy user's data in the form anyway and user can safely return to it once you dismiss that newly pushed in page.

Hope this helps.